# CSS 3 column layout of variable sizes columns

Tags: android, html, css

I am trying to create a 3 column layout where the center column is about 25em large than the outside panel column.

Flex won't work because on mobile devices, the width parameter is basically ignored in flex. No place I found on the www/google said anything better than flex sucks for mobile devices.

The solution provided here works great on mobile devices if the columns are all the same width. I could not figure out how to enlarge the center column without breaking the layout  [Previous solution (new issue)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30990953/mobile-friendly-css-multi-column-layout-that-doesnt-suck-like-flex/30991311#30991311)

How do I create a 'non responsive' (element items/text won't span columns) 3 column layout that is mobile friendly of variable column width?

Comment: I'm not exactly clear at what you're trying to do.  Have you considered using a column based css library like bootstrap or foundation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you have a meta link like below in your html head?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: That doesn't help with adjusting my middle column width. I am not following where you are going. Can you provide functional sample code?

Comment: I don't really understand what the problem is, maybe your can make fiddle out of it, but if your don't have the meta and want your website to look good on mobile then put that code in de <head>. There is no way around it.

Comment: no, that is not the issue. I need a functioning 3 column layout. Flex will not work with your proposed adjustment nor does it provide a setting to adjust a center column. I don't know where you are going with this, but this is not the correct path.  A working solution, I should be able to place inside of jsfiddle and see it work.

Comment: i.e.  http://jsfiddle.net/wsqLagfu/   (but that code allows text to span columns which will not work for my purposes.)

Comment: so you want fixed width? then just use pixels instead of percents, right? or maybe i don't understand your question, im sorry.

Comment: btw if you want to change the width of a flex column, you can do that with css like  {flex-basic: 300px;}

Comment: yes, fixed variable width. percentages or em (percentages would be better).  i.e. column1 = 25%, column2 = 50%, column3 = 25%.  No, nothing about flex will work. I beat flex to death the other day and even have a bug report submitted. Flex is a complete failure on mobile devices. Everybody says 'run from flex' on mobile devices. 10 people I know of have tried to get flex to function correctly on mobile and all failed because flex is a complete failure.